# How to decode UTF-8 encoded String using java?

Tags: java, utf-8

Actually i'm having String in UTF-8 encoded form in the mail. I want it to decode it. I use Java mimeutility.decode text. But it doesn't decode properly.
Example String

> =?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC40LLQtdGC?==?UTF-8?B?0JfQtNGA0LDQstGB0YLQstGD0LnRgtC1?=

When i used

> MimeUtility.decodeText("=?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC40LLQtdGC?==?UTF-8?B?0JfQtNGA0LDQstGB0YLQstGD0LnRgtC1?=")

it yields

> Привет=?UTF-8?B?0JfQtNGA0LDQstGB0YLQstGD0LnRgtC1?=

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two MIME-encoded strings concatenated together. MimeUtility.decodeText() can only handle one string. You need to break it apart.

Answer (score 5):

It is mime-encoded -- the "B" encoding, to be specific (rfc2047 section 4.1).

I think you can decode it using javamail `javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders` or `MimeUtility`
 class.